# Calculating plane dimensions on THREEJS

Tags: threejs-editor

I have a 2D plane in a 3D world. The plane can have any arbitrary orientation, so just getting boundboxmax and min, and do x2-x1 for width and y2-y1 for height won't work.
How should I solve this?. I was thinking about calculating the angles and rotate the plane so it's normal faces the positive y axis, this way I could calculate differences in x and z coords. But how do I do that?

Comment: Plane objects in threejs do not have finite dimensions.  What object do you actually have and what information do you have about it?  What do you mean by "dimensions"?  The lengths of the two orthogonal sides?

Comment: No i'm Sorry, I mean just a flat quad, Not an infinite plane from threejs. Like a regular plane object exported from blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a quad of any orientation and can get any three points of the quad (say `(x1,y1,z1)`, `(x2, y2, z2)`, `(x3, y3, z3)`) you can construct a `Line3` with points 1 and 2 and with 2 and 3, then use `Line3.distance()` to get each of the sides.